# Get data from database and write it back in again

Tags: python, sql, database, mariadb

I have written a function by reading an excel file and writing it to the database. This works!

Getting data from the database also works.

Where I get stuck is at the point that the function should read each row, calculate it and write the result back to the database.

I also want to find out how many rows were written in the database and then pass that number to the for-loop.

The first function is used to read the Excel data and write it to the database:

```
    def Load_into_database():
    file_path = label_file["text"]
    try:
        excel_filename = r"{}".format(file_path)
        if excel_filename[-4:] == ".csv":
            df = pd.read_csv(excel_filename, header=0, names=['Probe_Dehnung', 'Probe_Standardkraft'], sheet_name='Probe 1', skiprows=2, usecols="A:B")
        else:
            df = pd.read_excel(excel_filename, header=0, names=['Probe_Dehnung', 'Probe_Standardkraft'], sheet_name='Probe 1', skiprows=2, usecols="A:B")

    except ValueError:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "The file you have chosen is invalid")
        return None
    except FileNotFoundError:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", f"No such file as {file_path}")
        return None

    engine = create_engine("mariadb+mariadbconnector://root:pw123@127.0.0.1:3306/polymer")
    df.to_sql('zugversuch_probe_1',
              con=engine,
              if_exists='append',
              index=False)

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM zugversuch_probe_1")
    records = c.fetchall()
    print("Records", records)
    calculation(records)
```

The second function is to read each row from the one column and calculate it row by row and then write it back into the database:

```
def calculation(records):
    # query the database
    for record_id in records:
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM zugversuch_probe_1 WHERE ID = " + str(record_id))
        records = c.fetchall()[0]

        # Berechnung Dehnung
        dehnung = calc_dehnung(records[1])
        print("Dehnung", dehnung)

        sql_command = """
        INSERT INTO zugversuch_probe_1
        (Dehnung)
        VALUES(%s)"""

        c.execute("""UPDATE zugversuch_probe_1 SET
            Dehnung = %s
            WHERE ID = %s""",
                  (
                      dehnung.get(),
                      record_id
                  ))

        values = (dehnung.get())

        # commit changes
        conn.commit
        # close connection
        conn.close()

def calc_dehnung(value_list):
    return (value_list[0] / 0.123) * 100
```

After I run my code, I get the error message:

> c.execute("SELECT * FROM zugversuch_probe_1 WHERE ID = " + str(record_id))
> mariadb.OperationalError: Unknown column 'None' in 'where clause'

Unfortunately, I also have the problem that the ID in the database does not start again at 0 after I have deleted data, but continues to count.

Here is a screenshot of the database:
[Screenshot Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIJit.jpg)

Here is a screenshot of the Excel file:
[Screenshot Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwc5u.jpg)

Thank you in advance

Comment: your sql statements are vulnerable to SQL Injection https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Comment: yes, but that wasn't his question. Also, sql injection is only ever relevant if you're dealing with user input. I dont see any user input here, this seems like an offline script. It's ok to mention it, but thats not what's causing his error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it works!

it didn't work for the reason that I forgot the brackets in `conn.commit()`

Here is my new code which i got from @vinzBad

```
    def update():
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM zugversuch_probe_1")
        for record in c.fetchall():
            try:
                record_id, probe_dehnung, dehnung, probe_standardkraft = record
                dehnung = (probe_dehnung / 0.123) * 100

                c.execute("""UPDATE zugversuch_probe_1 SET
                        Dehnung = %s
                        WHERE ID = %s""",
                          (
                              dehnung,
                              record_id
                          ))

                conn.commit()

            except mariadb.Error as e:
                print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
                sys.exit(1)

        conn.close()
```

Here is a Screenshot [mariadb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eVkN.jpg)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: great that you could solve it. please up-vote the answers that helped you find a solution and you can also accept your answer to close this question

Answer (score 1):

c.fetchall() returns a list of tuples you need to unpack in your loop

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM zugversuch_probe_1")
for record in c.fetchall():
    record_id, probe_dehnung, dehnung, probe_standardkraft = record
    dehnung = calc_dehnung(probe_dehnung)
    c.execute("""UPDATE zugversuch_probe_1 SET
        Dehnung = %s
        WHERE ID = %s""",
              (
                  dehnung,
                  record_id
              ))
```

Comment: thank you. I tried your suggestion, but also get the error message:
"return (value_list[0] / 0.123) * 100 TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"
I changed the line 
`dehnung = calc_dehnung(probe_dehnung)` to `dehnung = (probe_dehnung[0] / 0.123) * 100` and now get the error message:
dehnung.get(),
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'

What can I do to fix the error?

Comment: sorry that .get was left over from your code, I removed it

Comment: I don't get an error message, but the "Dehnung" column in the DB still remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any reason why you're using dehnung.get() . The .get() function is used when you retrieve values from a dictionary, but dehnung seems to be a list (or number?). This possibly breaks your code in some unexpected way and confuses the sql engine.

you're printing that variable here

```
print("Dehnung", dehnung)
```

if thats the value you want to insert, simply remove the .get() the next 2 times you're using it.

You also need to unpack the values from the variable "record_id". I suggest you rename this variable to "record" because it isnt the record_id - its one line of the results from the db, which contains all the values from that line, and the id is only one of them (the first one). you can access it with record_id[0]

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM zugversuch_probe_1 WHERE ID = " + str(record_id[0]))
```

you're also possibly using the wrong value here:

```
dehnung = calc_dehnung(records[1])
```

you probably meant to use record_id[1] instead of records[1]. Again, I strongly recommend you rename the variable "record_id" to "record", this seems to be the source of some confusion

Comment: Ok thank you. I have now changed "record_id" to "record" as you described and the two lines:
c.execute("SELECT * FROM zugversuch_probe_1 WHERE ID = " + str(record[0]))

dehnung = calc_dehnung(record[1])


I now receive the error:
return (value_list[0] / 0.123) * 100
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You have to rename records[1] to record[1] remove the [0] in the function calc_dehnung(). I also recommend renaming the variable "value_list" to "value", because now you're no longer sending a list to that function, but only the number (or float) itself. What you're having problem with is realizing that the sql returns a list of lists (the records). One line of those is a list (the record) and one value of that list is the float that you want to convert. You should try and keep track of this by printing & using appropriate variable names.

Comment: ok thanks I tried it, but now I get the error message: `c.execute("""UPDATE zugversuch_probe_1 SET
mariadb.DataError: Data type 'tuple' in column 1 not supported in MariaDB Connector/Python`

Comment: This is the new code:
`def calculation(records):
        for record in records:
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM zugversuch_probe_1 WHERE ID = " + str(record[0]))
            records = c.fetchall()[0]
            dehnung = calc_dehnung(record[1])
            print("Dehnung", dehnung)
            sql_command = """INSERT INTO zugversuch_probe_1 (Dehnung) VALUES(%s)"""
            c.execute("""UPDATE zugversuch_probe_1 SET Dehnung = %s WHERE ID = %s""",
                      (dehnung, record))
            values = (dehnung)
            conn.commit
            conn.close()`